# Ploting points from sympy Segment3D definition. Extract the half of value of each item from dictionary in format "(1,2,3)"

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, sympy

I´ve defined points and lines via sympy bib and took them into dictionary format. Now I´m trying to plot the points and lines from dictionary via FOR Loop.But I become an error.

How can I take only the half of the value of each dictionary item and only in format as example "(0,1,2)"? Without "Segment3D" and "Point3D"?

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/.../2D.py", line 81, in 
l_length=math.hypot(pA[0]-pE[0], pA[1]-pE[1], pA[2]-pE[2])

TypeError: 'Segment3D' object is not subscriptable

````py
from sympy import Point3D, Line3D, Segment3D, Eq, solve_linear_system, Matrix, Basic
from math import *
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from numpy import linalg
from sympy.solvers import solve
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
from itertools import islice


# Punkte der Geometrie festlegen
points={'p0':Point3D(0,0,0),
        'p1':Point3D(0,1,1),
        'p2':Point3D(1.707,1,1),
        'p3':Point3D(3.414,1,1),
        'p4':Point3D(1.707,2.707,4)}
locals().update(points)

lines = {"l1": Segment3D(p1, p4),
         "l2": Segment3D(p2, p4),
         "l3": Segment3D(p3, p4)}
locals().update(lines)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 7]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure('1')
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

ax.text(p1[0],p1[1]+0.3,p1[2]+.2,'P1')
ax.text(p2[0],p2[1]+0.3,p2[2]+.2,'P2')
ax.text(p3[0],p3[1]+0.3,p3[2]+.2,'P3')
ax.text(p4[0],p4[1]+0.3,p4[2]+.2,'P4')


#koordinatenaxen Plot
P0=Point3D(0,0,0)
X=Point3D(5,0.0)
Y=Point3D(0,5,0)
Z=Point3D(0,0,5)
lX,lY,lZ=Line3D(P0,X),Line3D(P0,Y),Line3D(P0,Z)
x,y,z=[P0[0],X[0]],[P0[1],X[1]],[P0[2],X[2]]
ax.plot(x,y,z,color='blue')
x,y,z=[P0[0],Y[0]],[P0[1],Y[1]],[P0[2],Y[2]]
ax.plot(x,y,z,color='blue')
x,y,z=[P0[0],Z[0]],[P0[1],Z[1]],[P0[2],Z[2]]
ax.plot(x,y,z,color='blue')
ax.set_xlabel('x-Achse')
ax.set_ylabel('y-Achse')
ax.set_zlabel('z-Achse')


print(lines.keys()


e1x=cos(l1.angle_between(lX))
e1y=cos(l1.angle_between(lY))
e1z=cos(l1.angle_between(lZ))
e1=np.array([e1x, e1y, e1z])

e2x=cos(l2.angle_between(lX))
e2y=cos(l2.angle_between(lY))
e2z=cos(l2.angle_between(lZ))
e2=np.array([e2x, e2y, e2z])

e3x=cos(l3.angle_between(lX))
e3y=cos(l3.angle_between(lY))
e3z=cos(l3.angle_between(lZ))
e3=np.array([e3x, e3y, e3z])



for key,value in lines.items():
    print("two points of the line:", list(lines.values())[0])
    pE, pA=(list(lines.values())[0]),(list(lines.values())[0])
    l_length=math.hypot(pA[0]-pE[0], pA[1]-pE[1], pA[2]-pE[2])
    print('Line ', key,'length', l_length)
    x,y,z=[pA[0],pE[0]],[pA[1],pE[1]],[pA[2],pE[2]]
    ax.scatter(x,y,z,c='red',s=100)
    ax.text((pE[0]/2+pA[0]/2)*1.1,(pE[1]/2+pA[1]/2)*1.1,pE[2]/2+pA[2]/2+0.1,key)
#    ax.text(pE[0] * 1.2, pE[1], pE[2] * 1.1, 'p')
    ax.plot(x,y,z,color='black')
    plt.pause(0.3)
    plt.tight_layout()
    print('*************************')


plt.show() ```

Then this is the error I'm getting.

```python
C:\Users\gsger\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\python.exe C:/Users/gsger/AppData/Local/Packages/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0/LocalCache/local-packages/Python38/site-packages/scipy/optimize/2D.py
dict_keys(['l1', 'l2', 'l3'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../2D.py", line 78, in <module>
    l_length=math.hypot(pA[0]-pE[0], pA[1]-pE[1], pA[2]-pE[2])
TypeError: 'Segment3D' object is not subscriptable
two points of the line: Segment3D(Point3D(0, 1, 1), Point3D(1707/1000, 2707/1000, 4))

Process finished with exit code 1
````

Answer (score 0):

I think Point's allowing you to use indices led you astray. Instead of using indexing, try use the attribute for what you are interested in:

```
>>> Point(1, 2).x
1
>>> Point(1, 2).args  # all SymPy objects know what their args are
(1, 2)
>>> s = Segment((1, 2), (3, 4))
>>> s.p1.args
(1, 2)
>>> s.p2.args
(3, 4)
```

Note, too, you define `pA` and `pE` to be the same thing and I am guessing you mean them to be the points defining the segment. So I would suggest iterating over `key, seg` to remind yourself that your value is a segment and then use attributes within your loop:

```
for key, seg in lines.items():
    print("two points of the line:", seg)
    pE, pA = seg.p1, seg.p2
    l_length = seg.length.n()
    print('Line ', key, 'length', l_length)
    x, y, z = [list(i) for i in zip(pA, pE)]
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='red', s=100)
    m = seg.midpoint
    ax.text(m.x*1.1, m.y*1.1, m.z + 0.1, key)
#    ax.text(pE.x*1.2, pE.y, pE.z*1.1, 'p')
    ax.plot(x, y, z, color='black')
    plt.pause(0.3)
    plt.tight_layout()
    print('*************************')
```